# Module overwrite previous attached window mouseup event

Tags: javascript

I am currently working on a javascript module which open and close boxes, tooltip or similar, the function works great the only problem is when I call it twice on a page where the 'boxes' classes are different the window mouseup event will be overwritten and only one of the two module instances of boxes can now be closed after opening them.

```
var boxRevealer = (function () {
    var buttons;
    var boxes;
    var element;
    var drp_active = false;

    var boxConstruct = function (btns, bxs) {
        buttons = document.querySelectorAll(btns);
        boxes = document.querySelectorAll(bxs);
        boxEvents();
    };

    var boxEvents = function () {
        buttons.forEach(function (e) {
            e.addEventListener("click", function (ee) {
                element = document.getElementById(e.getAttribute("data-drp"));
                element.classList.toggle("displayn");
                drp_active = true;
            });
        });

        window.addEventListener("mouseup", function (e) {
            if (drp_active === true) {
                if (!e.target.classList.contains("filt_holy")) {
                    boxes.forEach(function (e) {
                        console.log("ELEMENT");
                        console.log(e);
                        e.classList.add("displayn");
                    });
                }
            }
        }, false);
    };

    return {
        boxConstruct: boxConstruct,
        boxEvents: boxEvents
    };
})();
```

Here is how i call the module

```
window.addEventListener("load", function(e){
   boxRevealer.boxConstruct(".head_drp_btn", ".head_drp"); 
   boxRevealer.boxConstruct(".mkt_drp_btn", ".mkt_drp"); 
});
```

So my question is, should I always name the boxes the same, or is there a work around?

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the event before adding it, I think the same event is getting called twice.

So updated code will be as follows:

```
// Attach an event handler to <div>
e.addEventListener("mousemove", myFunction);

// Remove the event handler from <div>
e.removeEventListener("mousemove", myFunction);
```

And remove the window event as well before adding it.

Comment: It is this event => 'window.addEventListener("mouseup", function (e) { }' that event does this 'boxes.forEach(function (e) {}' and when boxes has different class names than the previous call it wount attach an event to the previous boxes